# Xamarin Application - How to convert JSON Object to Image, read from Azure SQL DB

Tags: c#, json, azure, xamarin

I am not sure if I write my question correctly (my English...) but here is the situation:

1. Have a windows form application
2. This application storage image as byte[] to AZURE SQL Database (column type "image")
3. Have also a Xamarin mobile application
4. This mobile application want to read that image

For this have a DataModel:

Fist I try in my Model this:

`public byte[] AppUsers_Logo { get; set; }`
BUT got Error:

*Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException
Message=Error reading bytes. Unexpected token: StartObject. Path '[0].AppUsers_Logo.type'.*

then change data type to **object**.

```
namespace MPPCProvisions.Models
{
    public class tbl_AppUsersModel
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public int AppUsersNumber { get; set; }
        public string AppUsers_FirmaName { get; set; }
        public object AppUsers_Logo { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And try to read... whitch is ok but the converting.... no working :(

```
// /////////////////////////////////////////
// read AppUser_Logo from AZURE DB

var appUser = (await App.MobileService.GetTable<tbl_AppUsersModel>().Where(a => a.AppUsersNumber == 1).ToListAsync());
            
foreach (var item in appUser)
{
    byte[] appUserLogo = ObjectToByteArray(item.AppUsers_Logo);
}


byte[] ObjectToByteArray(object obj)
{
    if (obj == null)
       return null;
    BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        bf.Serialize(ms, obj);
        return ms.ToArray();
    }
}
```

Maybe can somebody help me: how I have to convert this object to get image?

Thanks for Help
Adam

Comment: why are you using object instead of byte[]?

Comment: also, it's generally a better idea to store an image in the file system or in blob storage, and to store just the path or guid in your db

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to deserialize your image?

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<byte[]>((string)AppUsers_Logo));
```

Comment: By this solution  I got Error: System.InvalidCastException
  Message=Specified cast is not valid. :(